# I am wishing to produce a series of smaller dataframes from a single large dataframe in python while naming the dataframes with the filter

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, string-formatting

I have a large dataframe called dfe filled with scientific information. In my first column ('reaction') there are three different string variables, say a,b,c. I wish to split this data frame into three dataframes dfa, dfb,dfc. I have a list variable called react2 with the variables a,b,c.

Here is my code for the problem:

```
for i in react2:
    df{}.format(i) = dfe[dfe['reaction'] = i ]
```

I then get an error of:

```
 df{}.format(i) = dfe[dfe['reaction'] = i ]
   ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Just for my understanding, what would you expect `df{}.format` to do?

Comment: Thank you.  I am wanting it to name my dataframes as it cycled through the loop. For react2 = [a,b,c], I imagined it would produce dataframes with the variable name: dfa, dfb, dfc. Is this not possible?

Comment: Oh, that clears it up, thank you. But unfortunately, that's not possible. Does the answer by @TBurgis help?

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. @TBurgis answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most sensible thing would be to store them in a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {}
for i in react2:
    df_dict[i] = dfe[dfe['reaction'] == i]
```

You can put this onto a single line using a dictionary comprehension:

```
df_dict = {i : dfe[dfe['reaction'] == i] for i in react2}
```